# Reading column of data into vector

Tags: c++, file, vector

I have an input file as such:

> ```
> 3  5
> 7  4
> 10 5
> 8  2
> 12 9
> ```

How can I store *only* the first column of those numbers in a vector (3, 7, 10, 8, 12)? The numbers are separated by spaces and if I do the following code below, only the second column of numbers is stored in the vector instead of the first.

```
if (arrivalFile) {
    while (arrivalFile >> first_arrival) {
      myVector.push_back(first_arrival);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
      myVector.erase(myVector.begin() + (i));
      cout << myVector[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the even location *correctly*

However, easiest way will be to use a `dummy` variable

```
int dummy ;
if (arrivalFile) {
    while (arrivalFile >> first_arrival >> dummy ) {
      myVector.push_back(first_arrival);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
while (arrivalFile >> first_arrival) {
  myVector.push_back(first_arrival);
  int dummy;
  arrivalFile >> dummy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of the erase, just:

```
while (arrivalFile >> first_arrival) {
  myVector.push_back(first_arrival);
  int skip;
  arrivalFile >> skip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read first value into number and second into dummy variable( just to empty stream).

```
std::fstream myfile("data.txt", std::ios_base::in);

int number, dummy;
std::vector<int> vNumbers;
// test file open   
if ( myFile) { 
    while ( myfile >> number >> dummy)
    {
        vNumbers.push_back( number);              // insert number into vector
    }
} else {
    throw std::runtime_error( "can't open file"); // signal run time failure
}
```